# How to represent a set of values of arbitrary length and type combination?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm writing code to analyze n-dimensional datasets. I wrote a class that represents an axis of an arbitrary dataset. Every axis can have a different datatype, so I chose to use template programming.

```
class BaseAxis
{
};

template <class T>
class Axis : public BaseAxis
{
public:
    Axis(const T &begin, const T &end);

    const T begin;
    const T end;
};
```

This allows me to create new Axis objects of arbitrary types. A user can configure a more high level class NTree which represents the entire dataset by adding the correct axes, as follows:

```
ntree = new ntree::NTree<float>();
ntree->AddAxis<int>(0, 8);
ntree->AddAxis<float>(-100.0f, 200.0f);
```

This would create a 2 dimensional floating point dataset, with an integer axis spanning from 0 to 8 and a floating point axis spanning from -100.0f to 200.0f. To get a value from the dataset you should be able to query the datastructure as follows:

```
ntree->Query(2, 2.5f);
```

I'm currently trying to figure out how to write such a function (or an object that can represent these parameters), since they can be of arbitrary amount and type. I've read about boost::variant but I'm unsure how to apply this in this case as I'm not experienced enough in c++ templates and libraries.

Here's the relevant part of code of the NTree class.

```
template <class T>
class NTree
{
public:
    NTree();
    ~NTree();

    template <class A>
    void AddAxis(const A &start, const A &end);

protected:
    std::vector<BaseAxis*> *axes;
};

template <class T>
template <class A>
void NTree<T>::AddAxis(const A &start, const A &end)
{
    BaseAxis* newAxis = new Axis<A>(start, end);
    this->axes->push_back(newAxis);
}
```

Therefore my question is as follows: how to represent a set of values of arbitrary length and type combination?

Comment: Is the number of dimensions fixed at compile time?

Comment: I think the appropriate methods are generated from the template during compile-time, but the NTree class is configured (by adding axes) during run-time. So AddAxis<int> is generated at compile-time, but it is executed during run-time an arbitrary number of times depending on the calling code (as in code block 2). So I guess the dimensions are not fixed at compile-time.

Comment: If you can change your AddAxis methods to be evaluated at compile type, then it would work using a typelist.

Comment: If the container is created dynamically using function calls, i guess you could clone allocators if you already encountered the type. But you need at least to define the typelist with all possible types the container will have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your container using a [Typelist](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&lpg=PA64&ots=YRgG1oOi6Y&dq=loki%20typelists&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q=loki%20typelists&f=false) or [variadic templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/). This way you could preserve strong type safety without using opaque containers. You can add and remote axis from the container, probably at the cost of copying the buffers over.

A clean implementation for that could use dedicated allocators for each type and a proxy class to aggregate them. You can then have a templated accessor in your proxy class which would cast the allocators back using the parameters and call their acess function.

This is a (very truncated) implementation of an N-dimensional container. In this case, a volume is defined by a list of arrays of same dimensions but different types, so not exaclty what you need, but close:

```
 // opaque base class for allocator
 class UnsafeAllocator{...};

 // specialized allocator:
 template<class T>
 class Allocator : public UnsafeAllocator {
      ...
      virtual T& operator[] (const size_t * position) { ... }
 };

 // proxy class for the container:
 template<class TL>
 class Volume {
 protected:
     // each field has its own allocator, allocated in the constructor
     UnsafeAllocator *opaque_allocator[Length<TL>::value];
 public:
     // put a constuctor with the current dimensions here and fill in the array of allocators using the typelist

     // typesafe getter
     template <int index> 
     typename TypeAt<TL, index>::Result &
     get(const std::initializer_list<size_t> &position){
           typedef typename TypeAt<TL, index>::Result FieldType;
           typedef Allocator<FieldType> SafeAllocator;
           SafeAllocator* allocator = dynamic_cast<SafeAllocator *>(opaque_allocator[index]);
           assert(allocator != NULL);
           return (*allocator)[position];
      }
  };

  // usage would be:
  typedef MakeTypeList(float, int, double) types;
  // define a two dimensional volume for each type
  Volume<types> volume({1024,1024});
  // example of typesafe access for the first type at position 0,0:
  float f = volume.get<0>({0,0});
```

The main drawback of this implementation is you need to know all the typelists at compile time. I don't know if that is part of your specifications or not.

If it is not, i don't think there is any way to have a container with a variable number of variadic types without using opaque proxys everywhere, which would kill the readability (and possibly the safety) of your code.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on "You can add and remote axis from the container"? I'm unsure what you're referring to here. Thanks for the enlightening advice so far. :)

Comment: By that i mean you can define more typelists at compile type by aggregating types to an existing typelist. Your addAxis functions would be evaluated at compile time to build up a final list which would then be used to define the volume.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation! It explains a lot. I'm wondering what <0> means in the get part though? And would this be valid? `float f = volume.get<0>({0,2.5});` Since the second type is double?

Comment: get<0> means you want to access the first field in the typelist, in this case a float. The type safety is guaranteed by the proxy class. My container is slightly different than yours, because the number of dimensions is fixed. Yours could recursively create wrappers around the volume class as you need more dimensions.

Comment: Again, just to be clear. I have N different arrays of different types but same dimensions, so I need to tell the method which field I want to access. In your case, since the dimensionality is dynamic, your allocator could redirect the call to a volume of type N-1 and so on until you end up in a one dimensional array and you can access the element.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot. I'll mark this as answered since you gave me enough direction to figure the rest out by myself. I don't think recursively wrapping will be the answer though as it's going to be an n-dimensional binary search tree when it's done. Thanks again!